# R, Package- Caret, function extractProb()

Tags: r, model, modeling

I am trying to produce a roc() for a predictive model and thus need the probabilities from extractProb(). I am following the vignette by Max Kuhn as a guide.

I receive no errors when I run extractPrediction() (code below).

```
> predValues <-  extractPrediction(models, 
                             testX = testTransformed,
                             testY = test_death)
```

However when I run extractProb(), seemingly the same code, I receive an error:

(code)

```
> probValues <- extractProb(models, 
                              testX = testTransformed,                         
                              testY = test_death)
```

(error)

```
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "obs", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
           :replacement has 4216 rows, data has 6324 In addition: Warning messages: 
           1: In method$prob(modelFit = modelFit, newdata = newdata, submodels = param) :   
           kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs 2: 
           In method$prob(modelFit = modelFit, newdata = newdata, submodels = param) :   
           kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs


> str(testTransformed)
  'data.frame': 1054 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ moi.0      : num  -1.497 0.667 -1.497 0.667 -1.497 ...
 $ moi.1      : num  -0.388 -0.388 -0.388 -0.388 -0.388 ...
 $ moi.3      : num  -0.302 -0.302 -0.302 -0.302 3.312 ...
 $ moi.4      : num  3.12 -0.32 3.12 -0.32 -0.32 ...
 $ gcs_tot    : num  -3.097 -1.776 0.204 0.534 0.534 ...
 $ tbi_surgery: num  1.831 1.831 1.831 -0.546 -0.546 ...
 $ time_2_hosp: num  0.0221 0.0191 0.0214 0.0261 0.0227 ...

> str(test_death)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

str() provided FYI. I have tried running extractProb() with test_death as numeric. No luck. There are no NAs in testTransformed or test_death.

What I am trying to do:

```
> models     <- list(svm = svmFit, gbm = gbmFit)
> probValues      <- extractProb(models, testX = testTransformed,
                      testY = test_death) 
> testProbs       <- subset(probValues, dataType == "Test")
> svmProb  <- subset(testProbs, model == "svmRadial")
> svmROC   <- roc(svmProb$pred, svmProb$obs)
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate probability? 
Let's say that you want the probability of each element of a matrix.

```
prob <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(yourdata)){
   his <- hist(yourdata, plot=F)
   for(j in 1:length(his$density)){
      prob[i] <- his$density[i]*(his$breaks[i+1]-his$breaks[i])
   }
}
```

You can adapt the code.